# improve odom by laserscan

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, laser-scan-matcher, laser-scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I improve odom of a robot by a laserscan- what package can i use?I don't have static, global map. I found [laser_scan_matcher](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher), but I don't know if it's still supported.
Maybe i should play with dynamic costmap and amcl? or maybe there is sth better?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139176/improve-odom-by-laserscan/) by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-12**:
AMCL needs a static map to match against. I've not used laser_scan_matcher but it does look promising, and there's a hydro branch in the source repo.  Is using a laser scanner your only option for improving odometry?

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2014-03-12**:
I think it is this option, but maybe i am wrong. What kind of improvement there exist (i know about IMU and this laser-scan-mach)

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-13**:
If you have a cmaera, visual odometry is pretty common (track visual features using cameras). Here's a ROS package that does visual odometry: http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also setup [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) to provide odometry. In the "correct_odometry_publisher" branch there are some changes and [this example launch file](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/correct_odometry_publisher/hector_slam_launch/launch/odom_test.launch) that has already been used for faking odometry on a robot to provide it to AMCL.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2014-03-12**:
This looks nice, but It provides odmo, not enchances one, right? I assume I'd have to make my own node to make this 2 odom sources "work together".

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-10-06**:
You can fuse two sources of odometry together with a Kalman filter, which if configured properly will improve your base odometry. `robot_localization` package provide a very nice and easy-to-integrate EKF implementation: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe  [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1